# Javascript timeout restart

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a module in my node app, which has a setTimeout function, which calls after every let's say 60 minutes. For sake of simplicity, you can understand that after every 60 minutes,

- it connects to some cloud
- query some data from it
- and saves it in my Mongo collection

  ```
    setTimeout(() => {
      fetchData();
    }, 3600000); // = 1 hour
  ```

Problem is that if any error comes in `fetchData` function then I throw an error and server's code flow stops and obviously setTimeout never starts again.

```
throw new Error(err);
```

Possible ways of errors:

1. login to cloud
2. fetch data by some query
3. logging out from cloud, and many more

So, I need some kind of solution where after throwing an error I can restart this setTimeout function, so that my fetching process will keep going on. I'm not sure if it's even possible, that's why I am posting here.

Please also note that, in real, this `fetchData` function is a module which consists of more than 10 files and lots of JavaScript promises.

Let me know in comments for any clarification guys.

Comment: why don't you use `setInterval`  instead of `setTimeout`? Also, 60000 means 60 seconds, not 60 minutes

Comment: ...and why don't you use a cron job instead of `setInterval` ;)

Comment: setTimeout is called  single one after DOM is ready and Given time like u give 6000 but u need to set setInterval to called function in loop please refer this sample code 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval

Comment: Are you using setInterval or setTimeout? you show code for timeout but talk about interval, it's very confusing

Comment: @Pete thanks. I have updated the question with corrections

Comment: @georg this might be my solution, don't know how I miss something so simple

Comment: @georg cron job worked...thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible.  You need to properly handle the errors.  This can be achieved with a simple try catch block:

```
function simulateError(){
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1) == 3;
}

function cloudConnect(){
    if (simulateError()){
        throw new Error("Cloud connect error");
    }
    else {
        return "Connection";
    }
}

function cloudQuery(){
    if (simulateError()){
        throw new Error("Query error");
    }
    else {
       return "Query results";
    }
}

function saveCollection(){
    if (simulateError()){
        throw new Error("Save error");
    }
    else {
        return "Save results";
    }
 }

function fetchData(){
      try {
          cloudConnect();
          cloudQuery();
          saveCollection();
      }
      catch(error){
          console.log("Error fetching data: ",error, " will retry in N seconds");
      }
}

//Now that fetchData handles errors with a try/catch block, the interval will continue to run every 60 seconds, 
//regardless of whether or not any errors are thrown
setInterval(function(){
     fetchData();
}, 60000);
```

Comment: I will try this. Thanks

Comment: thanks, it kinda worked but looks like cron is a better soln for me... but still +1